# Joining or merging two DataFrames based on index and column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group1': [0.5,5,3], 'Group2' : [2,.06,0.9]}, index=['Dan','Max','Joe'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Joe','Max'], 'Team' : ['Group2','Group1']})
```

My goal is to get the right value for the Name of the person considering the the column 'Team'.

So the result should look something like this:

[image]

I tried it with a merge but I failed because I don't know how to merge on these conditions.

What's the best way in Python to reach my goal?

Comment: What did you try? Did you search for other solutions? This question is featured in the pandas tag's wiki page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unstack `df1`, reset its indices, rename columns and merge on `Name` and `Team`:

```
out = (df1.unstack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename({'level_0':'Team', 'level_1':'Name', 0:'Value'}, axis=1)
       .merge(df2, on=['Name','Team']))
```

Output:

```
     Team Name    0
0  Group1  Max  5.0
1  Group2  Joe  0.9
```